# ¿Como comprobar el nombre de la URL sin extensión y parámetros?

Tags: php

```
function verificarURL($action) {
    $current_action = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");
    $current_action = strtok($current_action, '?');
    if ($current_action == $action){
        echo 'active open';
    }
}
```

Tengo esta función para comprobar si la `URL` es igual al de la página en la que esta y si es así, ponerle otro `background-color` al item del menu.

El problema reside en que funciona si la `URL` es "limpia" (ejemplo: `hola.php`), pero si la `URL` contiene parámetros `GET`, no funciona (ejemplo: hola.php?id=1)

¿Alguien podría identificar el problema?

Este es el código del `nav`:

```
<li class="nav-item start <?=verificarURL("addbook");?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>administration/library/addbook.php" class="nav-link ">
        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="title">Add Book</span>
        <span class="selected"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**CODIGO COMPLETO**

```
<li class="nav-item start <?=verificarURL("dashboard")?> ">
    <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>dashboard.php" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
        <i class="icon-home"></i>
        <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
        <span class="selected"></span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item <?=verificarURL("search")?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>search.php" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
        <i class="icon-magnifier"></i>
        <span class="title">Advanced Search</span>
        <span class="selected"></span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="heading">
    <h3 class="uppercase">CBS Library</h3>
</li>
<li class="nav-item <?=verificarURL("books");?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>books.php" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
        <span class="title">Books</span>
        <span class="selected"></span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item <?=verificarURL("authors");?> <?=verificarURL("author");?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>authors.php" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i>
        <span class="title">Authors</span>
        <span class="selected"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtok.php) divide un string en strings más pequeños, entonces cuando ejecutas tu código, coge la función `strtok()` el `'?'` como el `dividor` y te muestra el string como `addbook.php`

Solución:

Cambias la función del `strtok()` dando el tope al `'.'` para que te muestre como `addbook`.

```
function verificarURL($action) {

    $current_action = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "php");
    $current_action = strtok($current_action, '.');
                                            //^^^//
    if ($current_action == $action) {

        echo 'active open';
    }
}
```

[Demo Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/87f15d2d866b2307a5971533bd3bf156be68061e)

Comment: Si llamo la función con "algo.php", los que no tienen parametros GET no añade el "active open". Si cambio la funcion dando el tope al .php no me funciona en ninguno por lo que he probado. @aldanux

Comment: ¿Crees que es mejor que haga dos funciones para verificar, una par alos que tienen get y otra para los que no? @aldanux

Comment: Creo que me he perdido un poco, he vuelto a probar y no funciona. @aldanux

Comment: He probado de nuevo (copiando y pegando) y nada, no funciona. El primer metodo que me has dado funciona con los que tienen GET pero no con los que no lo tienen. El segundo nada, con ninguno de los dos. Crees que sería más facil crear otra funcion que verifique los que tienen get y una para los que no? Si es verdad que casi todas las páginas pueden o no pueden tener get, ya que los códigos de errores van en el get. @aldanux

Comment: Acabo de poner en codigo completo ne la pregunta. También he cambiado lo de <?= por <?php echo pero tampoco funciona @aldanux

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado con el "." que me has dicho. Muchisimas gracias por todas las molestias y toda la ayuda. Muchas gracias de nuevo. @aldanux